# How is the family of distributions with PDF proportional to $(1+ax^2)^{-1/a}$ called?

Tags: distributions, terminology, t-distribution, tsne, cauchy-distribution

Consider a family of distributions with PDF  (up to a proportionality constant) given by
$$p(x)\sim \frac{1}{(1+\alpha x^2)^{1/\alpha}}.$$
How is it called? If it does not have a name, how would you call it?

It looks quite similar to the family of $t$-distributions with PDF proportional to
$$p(x)\sim \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{\nu} x^2)^{(\nu+1)/2}}.$$

When $\alpha=\nu=1$ we have $t$-distribution with 1 df, aka Cauchy distribution. When $\alpha\to 0$ or $\nu\to\infty$, we get Gaussian distribution.

This family of distributions appears in [Yang et al., Heavy-Tailed Symmetric Stochastic Neighbor Embedding, NIPS 2009](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3770-heavy-tailed-symmetric-stochastic-neighbor-embedding), but they don't use any name to refer to it.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/t-location-scale-distribution.html. I would say it is a form of scaled t-distribution by setting corresponding values to v and scale.

Comment: Thanks @CagdasOzgenc (+1). You are right. Glen_b elaborated on this in an answer.

Comment: In case you are unaware of it, `mgcv::gam` allows the specification of a scaled-T as response when using `gam( family= "scat", ... )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply a particular *scaled* $t$-distribution -- a $t$-distribution with a different variance to the standard $t$-distribution.

Let $\nu = \frac{2}{\alpha}-1$. Let $\sigma= \frac{\sqrt{2-\alpha}}{\alpha}$.

Then (if I did it right) $Y=X/\sigma$ is a standard $t$ with $\nu$ d.f.

---

Here's how my reasoning went:

$$f_Y(y)= c\cdot \frac{1}{(1+\frac{y^2}{\nu})^{(\nu+1)/2}}$$ is a standard $t$-density.

We get the scale family by letting $X/\sigma=Y$, in which case $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma}f_Y\Big(\frac{x}{\sigma}\Big) = \frac{c}{\sigma}\cdot \frac{1}{(1+\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2\nu})^{(\nu+1)/2}}$$ is a scaled $t$-density.

Just equate the coefficients in your density to this, and solve for $\nu$ and $\sigma$.

Recognizing that a scale parameter will take up whatever isn't "right" in $\alpha x^2$ (given that $\nu$ is already defined by equating powers) was all that was needed to see it's scaled $t$; algebra wasn't required until it came time to actually find the parameters of the $t$.

---

[Final note: In case it's not obvious that a scale family has the form $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma}f_Y\Big(\frac{x}{\sigma}\Big)$, take the probability statement $F_X(x) = F_Y\Big(\frac{x}{\sigma}\Big)$ (noting that the event $X/\sigma\leq t$ is identical to the event $Y\leq t$) and differentiate.]

Comment: It's interesting to note that this conversion breaks down when $\alpha\ge 2$. I assume it's because the scaled PDF will diverge when integrated over the real line, right?

Comment: Yes. For example at $\alpha=2$ you have something that approaches $k/|x|$ in the tails, and so both halves of the integral diverge. Well that argument is a bit loose but you can tighten it up easily enough.

Comment: @amoeba Note that  $var=\sigma^2 \frac{v}{v-2}$. I use this distribution frequently for volatility estimation in financial time series.